# How to port WM to wayland?

Tags: x11, xorg, wayland, x-dwm

Are there any examples to port existing WM from X11 to wayland? For example, porting light-weighted WMs (such as `dwm`, `wmii`, `awesome`) to wayland. Maybe, portings `dwm` to wayland is a good example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some guys are porting Mutter to Wayland and gave a presentation about it on FOSDEM 2012. Here's the link:

- http://lanyrd.com/2012/fosdem/spghc/

Copied from the website link:

> Writing a Wayland Compositor
>
> Neil and Robert will discuss their own experience of writing a Wayland compositor, where they have been adaping the Gnome Mutter compositor into a hybrid X and Wayland compositor. The talk aims to provide general guidance on writing a hybrid X and Wayland compositor without going into many Mutter specifics.

This might be a starting point for you...

Comment: Link is broken.